# Matlab min function and 'lt' operator

Tags: matlab

I'm using `min` function to find minimum value in `Complex Double` array and set return value to slider `Min` property.
when user change slider value, find values that little than slider value.
but `min` and `lt` operator return different result.
for example looks below code.

```
array=[-5.61160893699794 + 1.29692613840634i , -0.000211300000000000 - 1.85290000000000e-06i; -1.91125106282203 + 1.60401019880518i,-0.768982324325300 + 0.732360902857864i]
vmin=min(min(array));
res=array(array<vmin);
```

result:

```
vmin= -2.1130e-04 - 1.8529e-06i  
res=  -5.6116 + 1.2969i  
      -1.9113 + 1.6040i
      -0.7690 + 0.7324i
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: why 'lt' operator return's value in above code?

Comment: Okay.  And, just to make my answer complete, what is the output you expect?

Comment: I think(not sure) 'lt' return correct result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the MATLAB documentation:

[**min**](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html)

> When X is complex, the minimum is computed using the magnitude
>       min(ABS(X)). In the case of equal magnitude elements, then the phase
>       angle min(ANGLE(X)) is used.

[**lt**](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lt.html)

> lt compares only the real part of the elements in A.

You can reproduce this behavior:

```
>> 1 < -2i
ans = 0
>> min([1,-2i])
ans = 1
```

Comment: so how to use `min' or other functions to find minimum value for real part of array elements?

Comment: how about `min(real(A))`?

Answer (score 2):

The expression `array < vmin` creates the logical array:

```
>> array < vmin
ans =
     1     0
     1     1
```

where the `1`s indicate that those elements of `array` have a *real part* that is less than the minimum value's real part.

And when you use that logical output as a [logical index](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7ekiy-1) like `array(array<vmin)`, the output is a column vector of the elements of `array` that are true.  So everything is working as it should.

If `array` were wrapped in `abs`, the resulting logical array would be all false:

```
>> abs(array) < vmin
ans =
     0     0
     0     0
```

which may be a more intuitive result.

---

I don't know if this is important, but I will note that the [`min`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html#burkwsu) function finds the value with the smallest magnitude (in absolute value) for complex entires while [`lt`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lt.html#bt297ps-5) only tests the real part.